# Which capacitor in series with resistor circuit to reduce remanence effects of transformer?

Tags: transformer, circuit-design, three-phase, magnetic-flux

The "[Comparative Analysis of Mitigation Techniques for Inrush Current of Transformer](http://www.ijirset.com/upload/2017/october/198_46_IJIRSET_Paper_Template%20Comparative%20Analysis%20of%20Mitigation%20Techniques%20for%20Inrush%20Current%20of%20Transformer%20_1_.pdf)" mentions "Pre-insertions resistor with capacitor method" as an inrush mitigation technique:

> When circuit breakers are opened transformer is isolated from network,
>   residual flux ([remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence)) remains in transformer and when transformer is energized
>   inrush current will be increased. In order to reduce above affect,
>   **capacitors are inserted** in primary side of transformer which reduces
>   residual flux...

and

> The presence of residual flux in the transformer is mainly responsible
>   for saturation of transformer core winding result in inrush current
>   phenomenon. In order to reduce the effect capacitor is inserted in
>   series with resistance.

The as [5] referred "[Analitical analysis of transformer inrush current and some new techniques for its reduction](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c285/c110abb62b2106070f5c6bf353139b295ef0.pdf)" shows a network diagram without showing how to insert the capacitor in circuit:
[image: Figure 2 ATPDraw circuit for network]

How does the capacitor in series with resistor circuit look like that reduces the residual flux inrush effect from a three phase two windings star (primary, isolated from network) delta (secondary) isolation transformer?

Comment: Residual flux can be removed by gradually diminishing the AC current. The BH hysteresis loop squeezes to zero during several AC cycles. In theory a resonant circuit could oscillate in that way. If there were no load, a capacitor in parallel with the transformer would do the trick but as well it would create another problem (=inrush peak due charging the capacitor) when the system is switched ON. In steady state the capacitor does not cause harm if the resonant frequency is near  the mains frequency.  I do not know real systems  with this principle, so I let an expert write the proper answer.

Comment: Maybe just short-circuit A-B and B-C while all 3 supply phase breakers are open?